# HttpsCallable Return from python

Tags: python, swift, flask, google-cloud-functions

I have an Xcode Application (written in Swift) that calls an HTTP python function that's deployed in Firebase. It should be getting a Response in return but for some reason, it always just returns when data is nil.

```
// swift function in xcode 

Functions.functions().httpsCallable("python_callable").call(["ID": ID, "time": String(currentTime)]) { (result, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            //does not enter this
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            guard let data = result?.data as? Data else {return}
                            print(data)
            }
    }
```

The following is a google cloud function that is written in python. According to [the Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#writing_http_content-python), Firebase function use Flask to work with HTTP Requests.

```
#deployed python Firestore function 
    import Flask
    def python_callable(request):
        ** processes firestore data ** 
        result = {"text":"example", "score": 100}
        return jsonify(data=result)
```

I know that the python_callable function is being invoked and that it is receiving the request however it seems that no matter what I do, I can't get the Swift function to get the response. It always receives null. Is there a specific Response format that httpsCallable expects/is `jsonify` used incorrectly?

Comment: Try this: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-functions/create-compatitle-cloud-function-for-firebase-with-python/

Answer (score 4):

"callable" functions are only supported on Cloud Functions by using the Firebase SDK for node.  They won't work for Python, unless you implement the callable protocol in the function itself.  If you want to invoke a regular HTTP function that you wrote in python, you won't be able to invoke it using the Firebase SDK on the client.

If you want to try to implement the protocol on the server side, the documentation for how callables work is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

Comment: Have you looked at [https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#functions_parameters-python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#functions_parameters-python)? It says that python can be used for HTTP functions with Flask.

Comment: Sure, but those are not "callable" functions.  Just regular HTTP functions.